# Magento shows attribute if value is left blank

Tags: image, magento, attributes, icons

I have a drop down magento attribute for warranty_labour. I'm pulling in the attribute using my themes product/view.phtml and then attaching an icon to show what warranty you get.

Ive used this code which successfully works:

```
<?php $warranty=$_product->getAttributeText('warranty_labour'); echo '<img style="padding-top: 10px;" src="/images/warrantylabour/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$warranty).'.png" alt="'.$warranty.'">'; ?>
```

The problem I find when a product doesn't have a warranty attribute set (left blank on the backend) I still get the code inserted on to the product source code on the frontend like this:

```
<img style="pad`ding-top: 10px;" src="/images/warrantylabour/.png" alt="">`
```

Is there a way I can stop this happening when a value isn't set in the attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget logic! :-) Just test that `$warranty` has a value Using typical Magento template conventions:

```
<?php if($warranty=$_product->getAttributeText('warranty_labour')): ?>
    <?php echo sprintf('<img style="padding-top: 10px;" src="/images/warrantylabour/%s.png" alt="%s"/>', str_replace(' ', '_',$warranty),$warranty) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This kind of syntax might justify encapsulating this logic and string building into a helper method, I think.